# SharpDX: ошибка при использовании swapChain.ResizeBuffers()

Tags: c#, directx, 2d, sharpdx

Здравствуйте!

В проекте c *SharpDX* при изменении размера окна возникает ошибка в работе метода *swapChain.ResizeBuffers()*: **HRESULT: [0x887A0001], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL/InvalidCall], Message: Приложение выполнило недопустимый вызов. Неправильные параметры вызова или неправильное состояние некоторых объектов..**

В *google*-поиске и в англояз.части SOF рекомендуют освободить все ресурсы, связанные c *pipeline*  - делаю очистку *device*, обнуляю *renderTarget*, меняю все параметры - не срабатывают.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

На первом скрине - метод изменения размера, на втором - инициализация устройства, цепи, таргета, на третьем - возникающая ошибка.

Метод изменения размеров:

```
public void Resize(int width, int height)
{

    ModeDescription modeDescription = new ModeDescription(width, height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm);
    swapChain.ResizeTarget(ref modeDescription);

    device.ClearState();
    d2RenderTarget = null;

    swapChain.ResizeBuffers(1, width, height, Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch);

    using (var backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(swapChain, 0))
    {
        var surface = backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>();
        this.d2RenderTarget = new RenderTarget(d2Factory, surface, new RenderTargetProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, ALphamode.Premultiplied)));
    }
}
```

Инициализация всего:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    //описание
    var desc = new SwapChainDescription()
    {
        BufferCount = 2,
        IsWindowed = true,
        ModeDescription =
            new modeDescription(Width, Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
        OutputHandle = this.dxControl.Handle,
        SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
        SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
        Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput,
    };

    // Create Device and SwapChain
    Device1.CreateWithSwapChain(
        DriverType.Hardware,
        DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport,
        desc,
        FeatureLevel.Level_10_0,
        out device,
        out this.swapChain);


    // Ignore all windows events
    var factory = this.swapChain.GetParent<Factory>();
    factory.MakeWindowAssociation(this.dxControl.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

    d2Factory = new SharpDX.Direct2D1.Factory();

    using (var backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<Texture2D>(this.swapChain, 0))
    {
        var surface = backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>();

        this.d2RenderTarget = new RenderTarget(
            d2Factory,
            surface,
            new RenderTargetProperties(
                RenderTargetType.Hardware,
                new PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, Alphamode.Premultiplied),
                96, 96,
                RenderTargetUsage.None,
                SharpDX.Direct2D1.FeatureLevel.Level_DEFAULT));

        this.d2RenderTarget.AntialiasMode = Antialiasmode.PerPrimitive;
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> HRESULT:[0x887A0001], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL/InvalidCall], Message: Приложение выполнило недопустимый вызов. Неправильные параметры вызова или неправильное состояние некоторых объектов.

Answer (score 2):

Метод *swapChain.ResizeBuffers()* так и не заставил работать. Пришлось обойтись костылем.

Все объекты у меня хранятся в словаре *Distionary(string, object) resCache*. В методе *Resize(int width, int height)* cоздаю *backupCache*.
Делаю очистку resCache и переинициализацию *SwapChain*, *RenderTarget* и *Factory*. Далее заливаю в resCache из backupCache при этом обновляю ссылки
на *RenderTarget* и *Factory*.